# How do I navigate on dispatch a success AXIOS call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I'm dispatching user `mobile_number` to redux store. On successful API call I want to navigate on OTP verfication screen. I don't know how to I do this with redux.

Login.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getCustomer } from "../Redux/Actions/CustomerLoginActions";

const Login = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState("");
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <div className="max-w-2xl py-2 mx-auto z-50 font-metropolis_regular bg-gray-500 min-h-screen w-full flex items-center justify-center">
      <form
        action="POST"
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          dispatch(
            getCustomer({
              mobile_number: number,
              country_code: "+91",
            })
          );
        }}
      >
        <input
          type="tel"
          name="mobile_number"
          className="w-48 h-10"
          placeholder="1234567890"
          value={number}
          onChange={(e) => setNumber(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button className="p-2 bg-orange text-white px-4 rounded">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Action component

```
import ApiInstance from "../../Api/root";
import { GET_CUSTOMER_LOGIN } from "../Types/CustomerLoginTypes";

export const getCustomer = (payload) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    const res = await ApiInstance.post(
      `customers/login`,
      payload
    );
    console.log(payload);

    // todo if api call success then redirect to other page to fill the OTP
    dispatch({
      type: GET_CUSTOMER_LOGIN,
      payload: payload.mobile_number,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

OTP page

```
import React from 'react'

const OTPVerification = () => {
    return (
      <div className="max-w-2xl py-2 mx-auto z-50 font-metropolis_regular bg-gray-500 min-h-screen w-full flex items-center justify-center flex-col">
      <p>Enter OPT sent to your number</p>
        <input type="number" name="" id="" />
      </div>
    );
}

export default OTPVerification
```

Comment: Why not just do it in ' .then()' of getCustomer() function ?

Comment: @Javvy7 like this?
```
          dispatch(
            getCustomer({
              mobile_number: number,
              country_code: "+91",
            }).then(history.push("/verification"))
          );

```
The problem is I'm getting an error inside my actions in my API call, but the navigation is still working.

Comment: Yes exactly.. if you are getting error from API call..add catch() block to handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add status on your state and return promise from your action, once action resolve change the status to success and in useEffect navigate to OTP

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getCustomer } from "../Redux/Actions/CustomerLoginActions";

const Login = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState("");
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('none');
  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === 'success') {
        // navigate OTP
    }
  }, [status])
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const onSubmit = useCallBack((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(
       getCustomer({
         mobile_number: number,
         country_code: "+91",
       })
    ).then(() => {
        setStatus('sucess');
       });
  })
}

  return (
    <div className="max-w-2xl py-2 mx-auto z-50 font-metropolis_regular bg-gray-500 min-h-screen w-full flex items-center justify-center">
      <form
        action="POST"
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
      >
        <input
          type="tel"
          name="mobile_number"
          className="w-48 h-10"
          placeholder="1234567890"
          value={number}
          onChange={(e) => setNumber(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button className="p-2 bg-orange text-white px-4 rounded">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

return promise from your action

```
import ApiInstance from "../../Api/root";
import { GET_CUSTOMER_LOGIN } from "../Types/CustomerLoginTypes";

export const getCustomer = (payload) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    const res = await ApiInstance.post(
      `customers/login`,
      payload
    );
    console.log(payload);

    // todo if api call success then redirect to other page to fill the OTP
    return dispatch({
      type: GET_CUSTOMER_LOGIN,
      payload: payload.mobile_number,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

install `history` using npm

then import and create browser history

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export const history= createBrowserHistory();
```

Pass this history to react-router

```
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';

<Router history={history}>
// your routes
<Router/>
```

Now you can call history.push() function to navigate from actions

history.push('/home')

Hope this is the answer of your question